# Error when installing KUDU : GSSAPI_SHARED_LIB (missing: GSSAPI_INCLUDE_DIR)

Tags: kudu

I am trying to install KUDU on an EC2 instance using the below official guide.

https://kudu.apache.org/docs/installation.html#rhel_from_source

In step 7 I see the below.

```
$ build-support/enable_devtoolset.sh thirdparty/build-if-necessary.sh
...

checking whether to build with GSSAPI support... no
```

In the step 8 I am executing the below step and getting an error.

```
$ ../../build-support/enable_devtoolset.sh \
  ../../thirdparty/installed/common/bin/cmake \
  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release ../..
...

Added shared library dependency cyrus_sasl: /usr/lib64/libsasl2.so
CMake Error at thirdparty/installed/common/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:218 (message):
  GSSAPI_SHARED_LIB (missing: GSSAPI_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  thirdparty/installed/common/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:577 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake_modules/FindGSSAPI.cmake:33 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:979 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ec2-user/kudu/build/release/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution thanks to KUDU slack channel. I had to install krb5-devel.